# Oracle 19c : Create Table If Not Exists

Tags: oracle, ddl, oracle19c

> A similar topic was posted 8 years back, Posting it again to check if
> any new feature is added. Please don't mark it duplicate.

I am trying to create a table with `IF NOT EXISTS` statement in oracle database 19c. But seems like it is not allowing me. I searched the web and found adding an exception for ORA-00955 error message will do the thing.
Please advise me if there is any new function/feature added also a piece of the code snippet will be of great help.

Here is the code that I have tried, it is giving me an error:

```
CREATE TABLE c##person.family IF NOT EXISTS(
F_id INTEGER(20) PRIMARY KEY,
FATHER_NAME VARCHAR(20),
MOTHER_NAME VARCHAR(20),
TOTAL_BROTHERS INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
TOTAL_SISTERS INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
FRIENDS INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
TOTAL_MEMBERS INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL);
```

```
Error report -
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
00922. 00000 -  "missing or invalid option"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Please advise -:

Comment: Nothing has changed. It **is**  a duplicate - and a look into [the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6) would have confirmed that

Comment: `c##person` leads me to believe you’re putting user objects in the root container, don’t do that. Use the user pluggable databases which don’t require special naming.

Comment: @AndrewSayer I am still learning the concept of pluggable data. do you recommend any course or tutorial to learn oracle 19c basics to advance?

Comment: Treat the pluggable databases as you would have treated the non-multitenant database. Treat the root container database a special system that you shouldn’t need to touch. If you’re new then start with the Oracle concepts doc https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/cncpt/toc.htm then the DBA docs https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/admin/toc.htm then multitenant https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/multi/toc.htm

Answer (score 1):

That's not valid syntax in Oracle. Here, you have to manually check whether table exists or not and then create it (or not).

Exception you mentioned means that they used PL/SQL (not SQL). We normally create tables in SQL. If you *must* use PL/SQL, then - as `CREATE TABLE` is DDL - you have to use **dynamic SQL** which is difficult to maintain and debug.

Therefore, if you just don't care whether table exists or not, just run `CREATE TABLE` statement; if table exists, it'll fail (but you don't care). If it doesn't exist, it'll be created (unless you hit some other error(s), of course).

For example:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_create_family
  2  AS
  3     l_cnt  NUMBER;
  4  BEGIN
  5     SELECT COUNT (*)
  6       INTO l_cnt
  7       FROM user_tables
  8      WHERE table_name = 'FAMILY';
  9
 10     IF l_cnt = 0
 11     THEN
 12        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE family
 13                             (
 14                                f_id             INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 15                                father_name      VARCHAR (20),
 16                                mother_name      VARCHAR (20),
 17                                total_brothers   INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
 18                                total_sisters    INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
 19                                friends          INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
 20                                total_members    INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
 21                             )';
 22
 23        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Table created');
 24     ELSE
 25        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Table already exists');
 26     END IF;
 27  END;
 28  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> exec p_create_family;
Table created

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec p_create_family;
Table already exists

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```